# Array of allowed values

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following two types:

```
type OrganizationType = 'NGO' | 'Business';
type Organization = {
    name: string,
    type: OrganizationType,
    weekdaysOpen: string[],
};
```

How can I define `weekdaysOpen` such that its elements are restricted to any (or none) of some predefined values? In this case they would be:

```
// Allowed elements in weekdaysOpen
'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'
```

Bonus if each allowed value can only appear once.

Comment: maybe you need an enum - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to allow only unique values:

```
type WeekDay = 'mon' | 'tue' | 'wed' | 'thu' | 'fri' | 'sat' | 'sun';

type Organization = {
  ...
  weekdaysOpen: Set<WeekDay>
};
```

Comment: Very elegant, thank you! Regardless, I'm in awe by all these quality suggestions appearing so quickly, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
type OrganizationType = 'NGO' | 'Business';
type WeekDay = 'mon' | 'tue' | 'wed' | 'thu' | 'fri' | 'sat' | 'sun';
type Organization = {
    name: string,
    type: OrganizationType,
    weekdaysOpen: WeekDay[],
};
```